# Como conectar Visual Studio Code com TFVC?

Tags: versionamento, visual-studio-code

Existe alguma forma de conectar o Visual Studio Code para utilizar o controle de versão do Team Foundation Version Control(TFVC)? Se sim, como fazer?

Answer (score 2):

Existem duas extensões atualmente disponíveis que suportam TFVC.

A extensão [Visual Studio Team Services](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team), da própria Microsoft, indica que a partir da versão 1.116.0 já seria possível conectar ao TFVC. Existe também outra extensão mais antiga, de um desenvolvedor independente, chamada [TFS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ivangabriele.vscode-tfs).

Você poderia testar as duas e verificar qual atende melhor o seu cenário.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possível conectar o **Visual Studio Code** com o controle de versão **TFVC**, para isso faz-se necessário utilizar a extensão do **[Visual Studio Team Services](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team)**.

Recentemente foi publicado no Blog "Microsoft DevOps" o seguinte artigo contendo as informações necessárias: ***[Official Release of TFVC Support for Visual Studio Code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/04/12/official-release-of-tfvc-support-for-visual-studio-code/)***

É possível rever a **[documentação do projeto](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#team-foundation-version-control-tfvc-support)**.

Também foi disponibilizado um vídeo mostrando a integração de ambos recursos: [**TFVC Source Code Control in Visual Studio Code**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IzJ2UPGmoQ&feature=youtu.be)